# Async string assignment, GetAwaiter?

Tags: wpf, string, asynchronous, async-await

I am assigning a large string to a WPF textblock, and i would like to make this happen asynchronously, or even 'streamed' into the new location. I am curious if I can extend the string class to have a GetAwaiter(), any thoughts? This doesnt need to be fancy, but I dont like the way it locks up when assigning large strings.

```
private async void listBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ready && listOfData.Count > 0 && listBox.SelectedIndex >= 0) // this prevents issues when called by reloading (which counts as selection change)
    {
        var idx = listBox.SelectedIndex;
        ResultBlock.Text = listOfData[idx]; // *** THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN ASYNC/PARALLEL/ETC
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to set the Text property of a TextBlock asynchronously if that's what you are asking. This is a simple CLR property and you can't set these asynchronously.

Comment: I know i have populated other WPF components (listbox, combo, etc) with threaded tasks before -- but with this example its a simple 'string' assignment, it just happens to lock up the main thread which looks like a crash to the user. Is there really no way to do this? It is not necessary for the text to visually load in smoothly - it can just appear when finished -- but I don't want it to lock up when there is 1+MB of text to assign.

Comment: @MichaelMeritt why dont you update the text in background thread? i believe that should work.